# Linux Gigabit driver that survives resume

Tags: linux, gigabit-ethernet

Currently, I'm using the r8169 driver (Realtek 8169 gigabit ethernet). I tried both the chips on the mainboard and with an external network card. When I boot my PC, the machine comes up with speed = 1000 and speed is as expected.

When I resume after suspend to disk, the speed drops to 100. The driver doesn't support renegotiation or setting the speed with ethtool. Sometimes, I can fix the issue by `rmmod r8169` the driver and loading it again. But lately, the chip doesn't come up completely, either the speed is 10 or "up" is false.

I'm sick of [this issue](http://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10130). Can someone recommend a network driver (and a gigabit network card) that survives suspend/resume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intel e1000 in my laptop survives resume, but only ~20 times before thinking it's linked at 100/full (except plug in a 100mb switch and it's dead)

Anything that can handle PCI hotplug should be OK.

Comment: I got an e1000 based card and this driver seems to be better. Thanks!